# Django password reset flow without UIDB64

Tags: django, django-authentication

A team at our company is working on a new app. This app will consist of a javascript frontend and a Django backend (using graphql to communicate between the two). I am working on the Django backend and I'm the sole backend developer of the project.

We are currently working on the 'reset_password' functionality, which will follow the familiar pattern of clicking a button, receiving an email with a password reset link that will lead to the an 'reset_password' form. Though the frontend will render all of the forms, it's the backend thats handling the logic.

The code that I've written is borrowing heavily from the default `django.contrib.auth` views / forms. The link in the email consists both of an token (created with a `PasswordResetTokenGenerator().make_token(user)` call) and a uid (created with a `urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk))` call).

However, my frontend colleagues asked me if it would be possible to forgo using the `uid` (of any other fields that can be used to identify the user) and instead 'work backwards' from the token to the user. Now I know that the token is generated with the user (as its provided as an argument in the create token call: `PasswordResetTokenGenerator().make_token(user)`) But so far it seems that its impossible to use a token to retrieve the user that was used to create it. (It has also occured to me that being able to do so would be a security risk)

So my question is as follows: Am I correct in believing that its impossible (or at the very least undesirable) to use a token to get the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood `PasswordResetTokenGenerator` is using the `hmac` lib to generate an SHA-1 hash (cf [django.contrib.tokens](https://github.com/django/django/blob/45304e444e0d780ceeb5fc03e6761569dfe17ab2/django/contrib/auth/tokens.py), [django.utils.crypto](https://github.com/django/django/blob/45304e444e0d780ceeb5fc03e6761569dfe17ab2/django/utils/crypto.py)), so while *technically* it's not to be considered secure against an adversary with sufficient resources, I don't believe it's remotely practical to try to "work backwards" there in an everyday case where a simpler solution exists. You're correct.